# Get List of folder name in Views MVC Razor C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm try to get list of Controller foldername in Views.

Example: subfolder in Views

- Account
- Home
- Pages
- User

can i possible to get list of subfolder in views? i need to help.. how script to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will list the full path of sub folders in the views folder

```
public ActionResult GetViewFolders()
{
  string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("Views");
  string[] subfolders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```